Question about $B^{+}$
This question is in Grimaldi's book:
For $\Sigma$ = { x, y, z } , let A,B, $\subseteq$ $\Sigma^*$ be given by A = {xy}
and B = {$\lambda$, x}.
Note: $\lambda$ is the notation of the empty string.
Determine $B^+$.
I think $B^+$ = {$\lambda$, x, $x^2$, $x^3$, ...} which is {$x^n$ | n $\ge$ 0}.
But in the solutions manual $B^+$ = {$x^n$ | n $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}^+$}.
What is it that I am missing?
Thank you in advance for your help.

I've not read Grimaldi's book, but assuming that $λ$ is their notation of the empty string then you are correct, as for any set $B$ we have $B \subseteq B^+$ (or technically an inclusion map depending on how you define it). Thus as $\lambda \in B$ so $\lambda \in B^+$.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that $\lambda$ is the notation of the empty string.
